# Polygon built by vectors - find the biggest area, need ordered list of vertices

Tags: algorithm, vector, geometry, polygon, area

## Description

The program takes a list of 2D vectors, let's say A,B,C.. and so on. One permutation of those vectors describe a polygon the following way:

1. Starting point is a=(0,0)
2. We are taking first vector (A) and build a line [a;b] where b=a+A
3. We are taking next vector (B) and build a line [b;c] where c=b+B
4. ..and so on until we are out of vectors
5. We build a line [z;a] where z is the point of end of previous line (we just close the polygonal chain)

## Background

Generally, the whole program has to find the permutation of input vector list, which desribes the polygon with the biggest area.
The problem is those lines that are mentioned above can intersect. Additionally, I chose Shoelace formula (aka Gauss's area formula) to calculate the areas, which requires list of vertices that are ordered. But I can choose some other method if needed.

## Summary

So in total I need an algorithm that both find all vertices of built polygon (considering intersections) and order it in correct order for Shoelace formula or I need some other solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Vector addition is commutative and associative.  Therefore, you will end at the same point regardless of the order in which you arrange your vectors.

   closure_vec = (0,0) - sum(vector_list)
2. You don't have to worry about intersections.  There will always be at least one ordering of the vectors that is convex -- it has no intersections.  One of these orderings will have the maximum area.  When you have a choice of arrangement, a convex polygon will have a larger area than a similar one with an intersection.
3. I *think* that you can construct the maximal polygon rather simply: sort the vectors by heading (theta, in polar coordinates).  Use them in that sorted order; the result is convex and maximal.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you. I have next problem though.
There are some "boundary intersections" that are legal. For example - we have list of vectors that precisely close the polygon like (1,0);(0,1);(-1,-1). My program at current state would classify last line as intersecting with the first line and reject this polygon, which in fact is legal. Could you advise how can I find only "illegal" intersections that cause polygon to be self-intersecting and pass "legal" ones like mentioned above?

Comment: Please refer to the posting guidelines: (1) This is a separate issue, which requires a separate posting; (2) You haven't posted the failing code.  Until you carefully delineate legal and illegal intersections and demonstrate the problem with code you've tried to fix, we can't really help you.  The obvious answer is to fix your closure code: you apparently taught it to label this case as an intersection.  You wrote that rule; change it to include the case you just described.